# Question about Integral definition

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

This is from Spivak's Calculus chapter 13 where integrals are introduced.The definition he gives is:

"A function $f$ which is bounded on $[a, b]$ is **integrable** on $[a, b]$ if **sup** {$L(f, P)$: $P$ a partition of $[a, b]$ = **inf** {$U(f, P)$: $P$ a partition of $[a, b]$}.In this case, this common number is called the integral of f on $[a, b]$ and is denoted by $\int^b_a f$ "

Ok so if this is the graph of some integrable function from the examples:

[image: function]

So $L(f, P) = m_1(t_1 - t_0) + m_2(t_2 - t_1) + m_3(t_3 - t_2) + m_4(t_4 - t_3)$ basically the sum of the black rectangles.

$U(f, P) = M_1(t_1 - t_0) + M_2(t_2 - t_1) + M_3(t_3 - t_2) + M_4(t_4 - t_3)$ the sum of the grey rectangles(including the part where the grey ones are covered by the smaller black ones).

And he says that the integral is the integral of this function or the area under the curve between $a$(or $t_0$) and $b$(or $t_4$) is the $sup$ of $L(f, P)$ which is equal to the $inf$ of $U(f, P)$.Does he mean supremum and infimum?I'm a little confused, isn't the infimum of the black rectangles $m_2$?And the supremum of the grey ones is $M_2$, which is higher, so they can't be equal.

Answer (score 1):

He means "consider many different partitions and draw this picture over and over again. The sum of the black rectangle areas for each picture will be a number. The sup of the resulting set of numbers, i.e. $\sup_{\text{all possible partitions $P$}} L(f, P)$, if it's equal to the inf of the upper sums, is called the integral."

When I say "many different partitions," I'm being sloppy -- he really means "all *possible* partititions, no matter how many points they may contain."

Comment: yeah after visualizing it I figured out he was basically trying to say that they're like divided into an infinite amount of ultra thin rectangles where the thin black one's top points touch the thin grey ones....right?

Comment: Actually, what you've *said* is the intuition, but it makes no real mathematical sense. The cleverness is in making a wise definition that *does* make sense and captures the essence of the intuition -- kind of like the $\epsilon \delta$ definition of continuity.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the sup of *one* L(f,P), it's the sup of *all* possible L(f,P)'s for all partitions.

This involves so many partitions that it can't be directly calculated, which is why they prove ways to calculate it indirectly afterwards.